# complex numbers- how do I prove the following statement?

Tags: complex-numbers

given: 
$$
\left |  z_{1}\right |=\left |  z_{2}\right |=...=\left |  z_{n}\right |=1
$$

How do I prove:

$$
(1+\frac{z_{2}}{z_{1}})(1+\frac{z_{3}}{z_{2}})*...*(1+\frac{z_{n}}{z_{n-1}})(1+\frac{z_{1}}{z_{n}}) \in \mathbb{R}
$$

?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1184048/215011

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider of the angle from the origin of each complex number $1 + \frac{z_{k+1}}{z_k}$. That's $\frac{1}{2}\arg \frac{z_{k+1}}{z_k} = \frac{1}{2}(\arg z_{k+1} - \arg z_k)$. Add these up and see they cancel out to give $0$.

Comment: The "1" in the expression will affect the argument..

Comment: That's why it's multiplied by 1/2